# Error in sysic function in MATLAB for defining control system blocks

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink, visualize

I want to synthesize a H_infinity control system and I want to define it in the form of general control configuration like [this form](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/General-control-configuration-for-the-multi-H-controller-design-The-H-norms-are_fig1_254032041).
at first I define relations of blocks with each other:

```
s=tf('s');
w_1=makeweight(100,10,0.5);  % Weight for performance
w2_2=eye(2);                 % Weight for avoiding over qualify
w3=0;

G=[(0.806*s+0.264)/(s^2+1.15*s+0.202) - 
(15*s+1.42)/(s^3+12.8*s^2+13.6*s+2.36); 
(1.95*s^2+2.12*s+0.49)/(s^3+9.15*s^2+9.39*s+1.62) 
(7.14*s^2+25.8*s+9.35)/(s^4+20.8*s^3+116.4*s^2+111.6*s+18.8)]; %  a 2*2 Plant



systemnames='G w_1 w2_2 w3';
inputvar='[u1;u2]';
outputvar='[w_1;w2_2;w3;u1-G]';
input_to_G='[u2]';
input_to_w_1='[u1-G]';
input_to_w2_2='[u2]';
sysoutname='P';
sysic;
```

After creation of ***P*** the function in below will be used to synthesize the control system:

```
 [k1,cl1,Gam1,Info1]=hinfsyn(P,1,1);
```

But the code faces this error: ***Error using sysic (line 175)
There are an inconsistent number of signals in '+u1-G' portion of OUTPUTVAR***.

How the error could be solved and is there a standard method to visualize defined blockes in the code in the form of control system block diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

If `G` is 2x2 then `u1` must be 2x1 for `u1-G` to make sense.  But this is being fed into `w_1` which is only 1x1.  Hence there's a dimension problem, and `sysic` is showing that. How to fix that will depend on the block diagram you are actually trying to create.

It's also not clear why you are using W3 at all, as you aren't connecting it to anything.

There's no tool for creating a visualization of the individual components showing how they are connected.  You could create a model yourself using Simulink, where each component would be represented by using the [LTI System](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/ltisystem.html) block, see [Import LTI Model Objects into Simulink](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/import-lti-model-objects-into-simulink.html) for an example.

Comment: Thanks, if u1  be 2x1 can, can G that is 2*2  be subtracted from it? two matrices for subtraction shouldn't be at same dimension?

Comment: The notation is saying that **the output of** `G` is being subtracted from `u1`.  Given that that output of `G` is actually `G*u2` then you need the dimension of `u1` to be the same as the dimension of `G*u2` (not `G` itself.)  Based on your data, `u1` and `u2` both need to be size 2x1.